# How t get total count of a collection in firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in cloud firestore. i want to get the total number of records in that collection, i can able to query all records and get the total count by using `size()` method, but when the collection grows huge, like say (10K) records, the get query is taking long time. Similarly for 20K it will take a lot of time, So i want to know if there is a way to get total count in cloud firestore by any inbuild methods? i want to get rid of the performance problems.Can someone please help on this? Thanks

My programming language is JAVA